# What can cause an rsync error no such file or directory (2) when syncing 2 netware servers?

Tags: rsync

I have this rsync command that syncs 2 netware FS volumes. I am logged into netware via a novell client with read/write/execute/filescan/access control rights in both the source and target servers.

The command is

```
   rsync -r -L -H -g -o -p -t -a --stats --human-readable --itemize-changes --verbose --log-format="[%t] [%i] (Last Modified: %M) (bytes: %-10l) %-100n" --log-file=/var/log/ram_sys1/$FILENAME /root/Desktop/H/ /root/Desktop/T/
```

and the output has these type of errors but the folders actually exist in the source (it is browsable)

```
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] file has vanished: "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Audit/SC audit/2012/Others/IML/2011"
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] file has vanished: "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Audit/SC audit/2012/Others/IML/2012"
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Audit/SC audit/2012/Others/IML/2010" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Audit/SC audit/2012/Preliminary Examination Findings" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Audit/SC audit/2012/Response to SC Report" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Audit/SC audit/2014" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Breach Record" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Briefing" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Capricorn" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Compliance Plan & Programs" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Compliance Review" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Compliance Test" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Conflict of Interest" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Disaster Recovery Test" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/New folder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Nomination of Directors and Rating Committee Members" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Personal Investment" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Policies & Guidelines" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Rating Committee" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Registration" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Reports" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Risk Management" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Scanned letters" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/Survey" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Common/TOR" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Elyse" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/Sharon" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Compliance/ZAABA" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Data&Analytics" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Insurance" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/RAs" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: opendir "/root/Desktop/H/USERS/Research" failed: No such file or directory (2)
2014/05/26 18:11:29 [14987] rsync: failed to set times on "/root/Desktop/T/.": Permission denied (13)
```

Can this be caused due to network issues?

Appreciate any feedback.

Edit: If I run a custom job to these folders it gives me the same error unless I put single quotes around the source and target paths.

If I use -R option in the original script and only define the parent folder which has no white spaces then do I still need to use the single quotes to guarantee that the subfolders under the parent will be found properly?

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be caused due to network issues?

Highly unlikely.

(If) The errors are reproducable and follow network-independant-patterns as you described.

> failed: No such file or directory (2)

This happens when you tell rsync to sync symbolic links that do not point to a target AND use "-L".

There may be other causes for the same error message. I just mention the "link" case to point you into another direction besides the "quotes" case.

Besides, some of the files in your example output do NOT have spaces in their names but produce the same error.